# How to read values from property file using innosetup?

Tags: inno-setup, properties-file

I'm trying to read values from demo.properties file using innnosetup.Here is my demo.properties file `hibernate.connection.username=James
hibernate.connection.password=Jack
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://8080/clientDB
hibernate.connection.driver_class=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`
I want to read this file and show values as James,Jack and 8080 in user interface.
Can anybody guide me how to get only those particular values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guide:

- Use Pascal-Script in the `[code]` section
- Work with `LoadStringsFromFile()` (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringsfromfile) to get the file content.
- Iterate over the lines using a `for` loop
- Use `Pos()` (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_pos.htm) to find the position of the `=` sign
- Use `Copy()` (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_copy.htm) extract key and value from the current line using the position of `=`

In case you need more functions take a look here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions

A problem close to yours has been solved here: [Find and read specific string from config file with Pascal Script in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789494/find-and-read-specific-string-from-config-file-with-pascal-script-in-inno-setup)